# PHP: How to construct zip file from database (or binary file content)?

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I need to create a zip file with PHP, but the source files are in database rather than stored on disk. Actually, file contents I want to pack are stored as binary in one database, and metas in another.

I have read the docs of class ZipArchive, but it seems that it could only pack files from disk (because file_names are required). I don't want to save files from database to disk, and then pack them, because it may slow down my application. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please see this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php

Comment: thanks, I ignored this method because I thought it is not binary safe for its name containing "string". Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ZipArchive::addFromString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php)?